# NavigationalView unknown color

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am new to Android Studio and I am trying to add a side navigational bar for my app.
But I am receiving an error stating that the class 
 android.support.design.widget.NavigationalView has not been instantiated.

I am unable to see my menu or the navigational header I created.
I previously had the same problem with the Drawer layout.
But I was able to solve it by changing the dependencies in build.gradle from  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'and 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3' to 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'and 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'.

Right now I am trying to fix the error with my navigational view.
Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorGrey">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here are my build.gradle dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bah.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Here is the Error I am receiving:

[image: Code Error Image]

Comment: Extra f on `#ffff`?

Comment: Hey Guys, thank you so much. I have been trying to fix this bug for an entire day. And all I had to do was change my colors at the styles.xml file. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the navigation view background to be `@android:color/white`

If that doesn't fix it, you have some other color within your styles.xml that cannot be parsed

Comment: Thank you so much!!. I edited my colors int the styles.xml file. And it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those rare cases where reading the Exception is *actually* helpful :D

Your exception says it couldn't figure out what color you're trying to use. That's because, as @cricket_007 commented, your NavigationView's `android:background` attribute says `#ffff` instead of `#fff` or `#ffffff`.

Cheers!

Comment: I believe ARGB values can have 4 characters, but I'm not sure alpha can be used for view backgrounds

Comment: Thank you so much!!. I edited my colors int the styles.xml file. And it worked!!!